# Git, Node.js and NPM on public server

Tags: json, node.js, git, package.json, progressive-web-apps

I have install Git, Node.js and NPM on my machine and have successfully been able to run a progressive web app on Chrome through the LocalHost. Now what about when I want to run this web app on a public server? Will I have to install Git, Node.js and NPM on my web hosting account? Or are these components already installed on web hosting servers in general (like would be an app like cPanel)?

By the way, would you be able to recommend any good FTP application for Mac that can upload zillions of files easily (not 1 by 1)?

Comment: You will have to get a public server that supports node.js
Once you do, it's all fairly self-explanatory from there

Answer (score 0):

You will need Node on the host server, but not NPM or Git (although NPM will be there by default when you install Node).

Typically what you want is to setup a "Continuous Integration / Continuous Delivery" platform. You can use free options like Travis or Jenkins or you can just use a shell script and run it through AWS Lambda or something like that.

Very simplified version:

1. You push code to Git
2. CI/CD detects the code check-in (polls) and pulls latest from Git on an Agent
3. CI/CD runs a "build" on the Agent, which for Node is at least `npm install` but can include Grunt, Gulp, Webpack, or a host of other useful steps.
4. CI/CD publishes the result of the build to a target server.

Here you have five machines involved:

1. Git server
2. Your local dev box
3. CI/CD server
4. CI/CD agent
5. production server

Hope this helps you get started in the right direction.